# Python TensorFlow: ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, python-3.5

I'm trying to run a 2-layer convolutional net for digit recognition on MNIST data-set using Tensorflow in Python3.5. The input is from csv files which I have read in as pandas dataframe. Tensorflow doesn't like pandas dataframe (it didn't accept the input), so I changed it to a numpy array. The following is the entire code-

```
sess=tf.InteractiveSession()

train=pd.read_csv('train (1).csv',sep=',',header=0,dtype='float32')
x_train=train.iloc[:,1:]
y_train=train.iloc[:,0]
onehot=OneHotEncoder()
y_train=y_train.reshape(-1,1)
y_train=onehot.fit_transform(y_train)

test=pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep=',',header=0)

x=tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 784])
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

W=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([784,10]))
b=tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

y=tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x,W) +b )

def weight_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.1)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def bias_variable(shape):
  initial = tf.constant(0.1, shape=shape)
  return tf.Variable(initial)

def conv2d(x, W):
  return tf.nn.conv2d(x, W, strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding='SAME')

def max_pool_2x2(x):
  return tf.nn.max_pool(x, ksize=[1, 2, 2, 1],
                        strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')

W_conv1 = weight_variable([5, 5, 1, 32])
b_conv1 = bias_variable([32])

x_train= x_train.as_matrix()
x_image = tf.reshape(x_train, [-1,28,28,1])

h_conv1 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(x_image, W_conv1) + b_conv1)
h_pool1 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv1)

W_conv2 = weight_variable([5, 5, 32, 64])
b_conv2 = bias_variable([64])

h_conv2 = tf.nn.relu(conv2d(h_pool1, W_conv2) + b_conv2)
h_pool2 = max_pool_2x2(h_conv2)

W_fc1 = weight_variable([7 * 7 * 64, 1024])
b_fc1 = bias_variable([1024])

h_pool2_flat = tf.reshape(h_pool2, [-1, 7*7*64])
h_fc1 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(h_pool2_flat, W_fc1) + b_fc1)

keep_prob = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
h_fc1_drop = tf.nn.dropout(h_fc1, keep_prob)

W_fc2 = weight_variable([1024, 10])
b_fc2 = bias_variable([10])

y_conv = tf.matmul(h_fc1_drop, W_fc2) + b_fc2

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_conv, y_))
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-4).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y_conv,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))

sess.run(tf.initialize_all_variables())

k=0
for i in range(20000):
  x_batch = x_train[k*100:k+100,:]
  y_batch = y_train[k*100:k+100,:]
  if i%100 == 0:
    train_accuracy = accuracy.eval(feed_dict={
        x:x_batch, y_: y_batch, keep_prob: 1.0})
    print("step %d, training accuracy %g"%(i, train_accuracy))
  train_step.run(feed_dict={x: x_batch, y_: y_batch, keep_prob: 0.5})
  k+=1
```

The error which I'm getting is in the accuracy.eval function-

```
accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction,tf.float32))
```

The following is the error message-

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

I tried looking up why the error occurs, and there were several reasons for it. However, my input is in the form of an array and I'm not really familiar with tensors, so I'm trouble understanding what is going wrong.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: x_batch and y_batch definitions are a bit weird. Aslo, consider reading about PEP8 to format your code

Comment: What are shapes of your `x_train` and `y_train`? `x_train[k*100:k+100,:]` looks not right, how about changing to `x_train[k*100:k*100+100,:]` ?